# Spring MVC 3.0 Annotated controller not working with JQuery $.post()

Tags: jquery, spring, model-view-controller, post, annotations

In the Spring MVC controller i am trying to access the name sent by the JQuery simple post. 
I am getting error **Could not find @PathVariable [name] in @RequestMapping***
Where i am going wrong?

**JQuery Post**

```
$.post("addName.htm",{ name: "John"});
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addName.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setAllocations(@PathVariable String name) {

    System.out.println("inside Setting value.... ");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

I am getting error

***Could not find @PathVariable [name] in @RequestMapping***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a `@PathVariable`, you have to use a `@RequestParam` instead.  Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addName.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setAllocations(@RequestParam String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

This is the difference:

- PathVariable: `http://yourhost/{name}/addName.html`
- RequestParam: `http://yourhost/addName.html?name={name}`

Comment: exactly, a @PathVariable would be embedded in the URL main part, such as "/addName/{name}"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addName.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setAllocations(@RequestParam String name) {
  System.out.println("inside Setting value.... ");
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

From the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html):

1. @PathVariable annotated parameters for access to URI template variables.
2. @RequestParam annotated parameters for access to specific Servlet request parameters.